# Synchronized block won't lock

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

There are falling snowballs. and when the snowball reaches a certain block (125<=y<=260) that block can only allow one snowball at a time to pass. The problem in my code is, they all pass on that block. It doesn't lock.

What is wrong with my code? Please help.

```
public void run()   {
    while(true){
        synchronized(this){
            if((y>=125)&&(y<=260)){
                    y+=1;                   
            }
        }

        if(y>=480){
            x = randomGenerator.nextInt(400);
            y = 0;  
        }else{
            y=y+1;
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you possibly have different instances of the object with the `run()` method.? The monitor object is `this` and that would be different for them all.

Comment: No. I used run() just in this method

Comment: This is the code for the snowball, right? You should synchronize on the block

Comment: That was not what I asked. That `run()` method belongs to some class. Do you have multiple objects of that class, and expect them to be synchronized with each other? They won't do that, because each only synchronized relative to *themselves*, because you synchronize with `this`.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos so you mean I need a separate method for sychronizing?

Comment: +1 for a question where people overlook the simple problem

Answer (score 3):

If each snowball is its own instance, each one will synchronize on itself (`this`), which will be useless. In order to make this piece of code work the way you want, you must have a shared resource all the instances can synchronize on. A good example would be the class object itself:

```
public void run() {
    while(true){
        synchronized(Snowball.class){
            if((y>=125)&&(y<=260)){
                    y+=1;                   
            }
        }

        if(y>=480){
            x = randomGenerator.nextInt(400);
            y = 0;  
        }else{
            y=y+1;
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd rather sync with a `Snowfield` (non-static) object (eg passed to the constructor) or whatever defines the coordinates that require locking.  But that's just from a software engineering point of view.  The class lock will work, too.

Comment: @5gon12eder definitely, that would be even better. I was just trying to illustrate what the issue was without adding any additional assumptions on the class' structure.

Comment: Thought so.  That's why I upvoted and left a comment for the curious rather than posting another answer.

Comment: Your answer is true, but I don't think it will solve the problem.  OK, now we have all of the threads synchronizing on the same object (Snowball.class), but so what?  Suppose snowball A hits y==125 just when snowball B hits y==124.  This example _still_ will not hold snowball B at y==124.  It will only slow the two threads down as each one locks the lock, increments its y, and then _releases_ the lock (potentially allowing the other thread to run.)  Worst case:  The two threads will take turns incrementing their y fields until both reach 261.

Answer (score 1):

You can use class level synchronization for global locking.

```
synchronized(YourClassName.class){
   // Your code goes here
}
```